# Fast switching of a 24V valve

Tags: switches

I'm trying to make a circuit using tc4427 and some other components to make a fast switch for a 24V valve using a signal from a microprocessor. I've modeled the signal from the processor as a pulse of 5V shown in V2 and the valve is modelled as a resistor R3 and a coil C1. Do you think this circuit will work fine?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must have a free wheel diode from the MOSFET output to ground, to catch back EMF. Using a TVS for that isn't a bad idea, since that will also catch various EMI spikes.

Answer (score 0):

The driver is connected to a 5 volt power supply so there's no benefit in terms of using the driver (TC4427) to increase the drive voltage to the MOSFETs gate. And the MOSFET will quite happily operate with a 5 volt gate drive: -

[image]

So, the only benefit from using the driver is to improve the current drive into the gate capacitance (circa 10 nF). But, given that you are only switching a 24 volt valve and, I suspect that the valve speed will be in the order of milli seconds (if not tens of milli seconds) then, using your 5 volt drive from the microprocessor (via say a 330 ohm resistor) isn't going to improve the timing much.

330 ohm and 10 nF have a CR time of 3.3 μs and if it takes a couple of CR times to properly drive the MOSFET that's only 6 or 7 μs wasted. Is this too much given the bigger picture of the mechanical valve sluggishness.

You will need a back-emf catch-diode across the solenoid to prevent the MOSFET from becoming damaged when you deactivate it such as this one across the motor below: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I had the same thoughts about the usage of TC4427 but I am  required to use it so i put it in. I haven't been told how fast the solenoid will be switched on and off As for the fly back diode which diode would you use in this application?

Comment: Which diode? It depends on your valve load current.

Answer (score 0):

You look to be well within the avalanche rating of the transistor, so I think it will be okay. Check the simulation in LTspice for the energy and power dissipation at the desired switching frequency.

The valve probably will behave somewhat differently than a simple inductor so you should confirm with a real circuit and an oscilloscope.

The valve release time will be related to how high you allow the drain voltage to go with respect to the power supply.